# Delete one string value from string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I want to remove one string from another string.

I first go with contains method,and then find on trouble when I find out that one string cointains another, I tried this:

```
someString -= anotherString
```

But that didn't work, and tried to do this with the replace function. But this also didn't work. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Read [ask]. If you've written code and it doesn't work, then show that code and explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: Provide us with some part of the code so that your issue can be reproduced then only others will be able to help you properly.

Comment: String is an immutable type, it means, you can't change the value from an existing string. Instead, you can use the function replace (or some others) to create a new string

Comment: Please, provide *examples*: what if `initial` string *doesn't contain* `another` one, *contains many times*, *ends* with `another`, *starts* with `another`, *equals* to `another`? Shall we consider *case* (e.g. if `"ABC" == "aBc"`)? What if we have *intersection*? E.g. `"ababaX" - "aba" = ?` is it `baX`, `abX` or `X`?

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `-=` operator with strings, and I guess you're having trouble with replace function because you use it the wrong way, it does not mutate an existing string, but returns a new one instead.
Try this:

```cs
myStr = myStr.Replace("STR-TO-REMOVE", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to make use of string.Replace function. Here is an example:

```
var stringThatContains = "This string contains the word Alpha";
var stringWordToRemove = "Alpha";

if(stringThatContains.Contains(stringWordToRemove))
{
     stringThatContains = stringThatContains.Replace(stringWordToRemove, string.Empty);
}
```

Result will be:

> This string contains the word

Please notice that instead of string.Empty, you can give any other string as needed.
For example:

```
var stringThatContains = "This string contains the word Alpha";
var stringWordToRemove = "Alpha";
var stringWordToAdd = "Bravo";

if(stringThatContains.Contains(stringWordToRemove))
{
    stringThatContains = stringThatContains.Replace(stringWordToRemove, stringWordToAdd);
}
```

Result:

> This string contains the word Bravo